# Golden Mean of Rectangle

Tags: proof-explanation, quadratics, golden-ratio

> ABCD is a rectangle with length and breadth in the ratio α : 1. It is
>   divided into a square APQD and a second rectangle PBCQ, as shown.
>   Show that the length and breadth of rectangle PBCQ are also in the
>   ratio α : 1.
>
> [image]

Also this question could possibly be wrong so please let me know if it is.

I tried proving it but I am stuck and I have been trying such a simple problem for hours still can't solve it.

Comment: What is $\alpha?$ For arbitrary value of $\alpha$ is the claim false.

Comment: What's to prove? Golden ratio is a number. You don't prove numbers, much like you don't drink numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your title mentions the golden mean a.k.a the golden ratio, I am going to assume that your $\alpha$ is the golden ratio i.e. a root of

$\alpha^2 = \alpha + 1$

(even though you do not state this in your question).

Rectangle $PBCQ$ has side with length $1$ and $\alpha-1$ so the ratio of its sides is

$1:\alpha-1 = \alpha:\alpha^2-\alpha$

I'll let you complete the final step.

Of course, if $\alpha$ is *not* the golden ratio then the claim in the question is false. For example, if $\alpha=2$ then $PBCQ$ is a square and the ratio of its sides is $1:1$.

Comment: Thank you! I think the question in the textbook is wrong as they are asking us to prove a false claim.